# Serilog Filter.ByIncludingOnly not working namspace

Tags: c#, serilog

I am using serilog (2.8) in my dotnet 4.8 application.Please see the code which help to initialize the serilog.

```
    var isxyz = Matching.FromSource("xyz.Dispose");
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Enrich.WithProperty("ServiceName", servicename)
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .MinimumLevel.Debug()
    .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(i=> isxyz(i))
    .WriteTo.Console()

    .WriteTo.File(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Logs" + "\\" + "log-.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day, outputTemplate: "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] {ServiceName} {CountryCode} {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}")
    .CreateLogger();
```

Here i am including only the namespace **xyz.Dispose**. So in console and File sink i should get only the logs from the namespace **xyz.Dispose**.

But after configuring above setting no logs are getting printed in console or file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filter is matching on the `SourceContext` property of every log message, so if no log messages are being written to the log, either you are **not** setting the `SourceContext` property at all in your logger before your write to it (*most likely*) or the `SourceContext` your are setting is something different than `xyz.Dispose`, which would cause your filter to exclude the messages from being written.

There are many ways to set the `SourceContext`, but a simple example would be:

```
var logger = Log.Logger.ForContext(Constants.SourceContextPropertyName, "xyz.Dispose");
logger.Information("This should appear in the log");
```

A common way to have the `SourceContext` property populated, is to use the generic method `ForContext<T>` in your classes. E.g.:

```
using Serilog;

namespace xyz.Dispose
{
    public class MyService
    {
        private readonly ILogger _log = Log.ForContext<MyService>();

        public void DoStuff()
        {
            _log.Information("This should appear in the log");

            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

In the example above, the `SourceContext` will automatically be populated with the full name of the class (`xyz.Dispose.MyService`), which matches your filter because of the namespace.

---

Unrelated to your question: `xyz.Dispose` doesn't seem like a good name for a namespace... `Dispose` is such a common method in any .NET codebase, that can cause confusion. Maybe use something that describes a group of things? e.g `Disposables`

Comment: Thank you so much. It is a sample code i updated here to illustrate the problem. In actual code. It is in proper naming conventions.

Comment: Just a quick question, Is it possible to use xyz.* in match filter

Comment: @Vipin Yes, if you use “xyz.” It will match anything that starts with that.